# How do I stop a rush as the British in AoE 3

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

So, I created a league for me and my friends to play some AoE during the quarantine.

I used to trash my opponents by simply following a few set strategies (I play as the Brits) To age and create troops as fast as possible.

But as my friends got better, they realised they can crush me by simply all rushing together. I'm no slouch (Colonial by 5-6 min) but I just can't seem to beat off early Hussar or Musketeer rushes.

What should I do? How do I manage my resources to have 15 Villagers, and age in time to create a military?

Comment: Related: [In Age of Empires 3, what is a good build order for the British?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4259/4797)